Idempotent elements of product rings
Let $R_\alpha $ be ring for each $\alpha $. Suppose $S=\Pi_{\alpha \in I}R_\alpha $ be direct product of rings $R_\alpha$. I want to prove $Idem(S)=\Pi_{\alpha \in I}Idem(R_\alpha)$, where $Idem(S)$ denotes the set of idempotent elements of $S$.
Here is my proof:
Let $(a_0,a_1,...)\in Idem(S)$, it means $(a_0,a_1,...)^2=(a_0,a_1,...)$ which implies that $(a_0^2,a_1^2,...)=(a_0,a_1,...)$ which further implies that each $a_i$ is idempotent element of $R_i$ and similarly the converse.
Is the proof correct?

You could be slightly more explicit if you wanted showing both containment directions, but you could also probably just say "follows from definition of direct product".

Yes, obviously correct.

Consider using \operatorname{Idem} for proper formatting of $Idem$.

Your argument correctly shows that $\operatorname{Idem}(S)\subseteq\prod_{\alpha\in I}\operatorname{Idem}R_{\alpha}$. To show equality it suffices to verify that for all $a\in\prod_{\alpha\in I}\operatorname{Idem}R_{\alpha}$ you have
$$a^2=(a_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}^2=(a_{\alpha}^2)_{\alpha\in I}=(a_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}=a,$$
meaning that $a\in\operatorname{Idem}S$.
